# GitlabCI migrate to rules from only/except

Tags: gitlab-ci

From what I understood `only` entries are logically combined with `OR`. So something like the following will add the job to the pipeline if changes are pushed to a branch called `develop` `OR` if a merge request was created. Is that understanding correct?

```
only:
  - merge_requests
  - develop
```

In the `rules` doc they say that the first matching rule of `rules` will decide if the job is added to the pipeline or not depending on what the rules are. So I would migrate above `only` to `rules` as follows and this seems to work as expected:

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
```

However, does the following `rules` section describe the same conditions as the above `rules` section or is it different and if so, how?

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
```

Answer (score 1):

As written, both the examples you've provided are equivalent because the evaluation of each list item under `rules:` is joined by a logical `OR`. In the first `rules:` example you provide, this is expressed in a single compound expression where the two conditions are joined with `||` (`OR`). In the second example, the same conditions are in effect, just spread over two rules.

Answer (score 0):

The key difference between the two rules sections is how the conditions are logically combined; In the first rules section:

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
```